# Understanding of microcontroller datasheet

Tags: microcontroller, datasheet

Generally if I start a project with new microcontroller, what shall be the extent of understanding i should have of the microcontroller. Should I be in a position to understand very basic details and each and every feature? Because I find so many details in the data sheet confusing.

Comment: Are you working with breakout boards (i.e. as a hobbyist) or as a professional working with a specific uC for an application?

Comment: Professional working with specific uC for application.

Comment: IMO you should know the feature set of the uC you're using in detail, i.e., the subsystems required for your design, power management, how to use timers, and the watchdog, the more you know about a specific uC line the better prepared you will be to utilize it in future projects.

Comment: But there are so many details such as clock jitter etc which never go into my mind.

Comment: You will have to decide which details are relevant to your design. Is clock jitter important? Should you use an external clock source with lower jitter/phase noise? You will have to research the parameters and decide if they are important to your application.

Comment: Only you can answer this fully, but, you need to be sure that (1) the device meets all your needs and that (2) you can meet all its needs. For 1. - you need to know about eg timers, ADC converters, I/O pin drive capacities, memory capacities (various types) , program memory and likelihood that it will be fast enough overall. And a lot more. For 2. you need to know required power supply voltages and accuracy and stability , references if relevant, clocks if relevant, ... . | Clock jitter matters only if clock jitter matters - only you can say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to design a circuit around a microcontroller and write its code, you need to know what you're doing.  That absolutely includes reading the datasheet of the micro.  There is no substitute for the person actually doing the design.

When you're ready to start writing the firmware, read the datasheet.  You do need to read all of it, but not to remember each specific feature.  The point is to remember what the various parts can do, not the details of how to do them.  Those can be looked up later.  However, you need to know that they exist.

As you read the datasheet, keep two things in your mind.

First, every time you learn about a new capability, think about how you could use it to advantage in your project, or realize that it's of no use to your project.  You start with a general idea of the firmware architecture and how it will utilize the hardware, but as you learn the detailed capabilities that can and should be modified.

Second recognize the difference between concepts and implementation details.  There is no point trying to remember implementation details like which bit in which register enables the UART RTS/CTS function.  When you write the UART code, you'll look up the details and set all the configuration bits as appropriate anyway.  What you do want to remember is that the UART has RTS/CTS capability, or maybe that UART 1 does but UART 2 doesn't, for example, assuming RTS/CTS is meaningful to your project in the first place.

The RTS/CTS example also works with the first point.  When discovering that the UART has this capability that you weren't expecting it to have, you stop and think for a moment whether you could take advantage of it in your project, even though you weren't initially considering that.

This last point also illustrates why you need to read over the datasheet during electrical design.  You can skim it more quickly then because you're not thinking about firmware details at that point.  However, discovering RTS/CTS capability on one UART and not the other may well cause you to change the electrical design.

Answer (score 1):

As always, it depends.

If you have a project with specific requirements and a uC that meets those requirements there is no need to know the capabilities of the uC you are not using. There might be an USB peripheral, or an LCD driver, or the Q-decoding mode of the timers, which you all don't need. Don't bother with those, *except* for where it might bite you. The default mode of certain pins might be LCD, so to use them as GPIO you must know how to do that. Peripherals tend to be un-powered / un-clocked at startup, so you will probably need to use the clock/power management features. Maybe not even in detail, there might be a vendor-provided library (cmsis or something equivalent) that will take care of the ugly details for you. But the quality of such code can be sub-standard, in whih case you will still need to dive into the details.

If, OTOH, you have a uC which you want to use in a lot of different projects, you will at least want to know what the various capabilities of your uC are, so you can asses whether certian requirements can be met. How much details you need to know to do this generally depends on the margin between the uC capabilities and the requirements. To utilize your hardware to the max you will need to know all relevant details.